# Emacs's frame slide up automatically when menu-bar-mode is off

Tags: emacs

I just compiled Emacs23.4.1 on Ubuntu12.04 with Gtk support,everything seems ok except when I turn off both of the "menu-bar-mode" and "tool-bar-mode" to nil(in .emacs file or invoke the command),the Emacs frame slide up(like "jQuery.slideUp()"'s effect) until there is only one row visible,and when I pull it down and release the mouse,it slide up again.
does anyone meet this problem before?what should I do?

Comment: FWIW I dont see that nature in emacs24 on ubuntu12.04.